# How to accept input from command line in Love2d

Tags: lua, love2d

I am writing code in love2d as a server(with both command line and visualized forms), how can i accept input from command line?

Comment: please provide more context

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
function love.inp()
-- Building a prompt
 _PROMPT='Input: '
-- Put out the prompt
 io.write(_PROMPT:format())
-- Getting input from stdin
 local result=io.read()
-- Do something with it
 print('Getting:',result)
-- Cleaning up...
 _PROMPT=empty
 result=empty
end
```

To reach that function try this...

```
love.keyreleased(key)
 if key=="c" then love.inp() end
end
```

Comment: thanks but where should i put this in? cuz there is a form, if i put this code chunk into the update() function, the form update will be suspended.

Comment: Replace ```do``` with ```love.inp()``` in the body and assign a key to it with ```love.keyreleased(key) if key=="c" then love.inp() end end```.

Comment: In the case you are using Windows/Mac you need to set ```t.console=true``` in conf.lua to output to and from a commandline - Look: https://love2d.org/wiki/Config_Files